# Why would Webpack 4 minification prevent styles for react-select component?

Tags: javascript, webpack-4, react-select, emotion, react-on-rails

I have a React project that is bundled by Webpack and served up by [react_on_rails](https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails). In this project I use the `Select` component from [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select). Everything works as expected when using Webpack 3. After upgrading to Webpack 4, everything also works as expected in `development` mode. However, when I build in `production` mode, the `Select` component from `react-select` does not have any styling applied to it.

(I don't have enough reputation points to post images so I am going to provide links to the images.)

Here is what the selector looks like when built in `development` mode.

[selector with styling](https://i.ibb.co/qyhnbdt/Screen-Shot-2019-04-03-at-11-12-22-AM-3.png)

And here is what the selector looks like when built in `production` mode.

[selector without styling](https://i.ibb.co/b7c5yqj/Screen-Shot-2019-04-03-at-3-36-00-PM-3.png)

The reason the styles are not applied is that `react-select` uses [Emotion css-in-js](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion) and the css gets injected into the head in stylesheets.

Here is an example in the head when in `development` mode.

[screenshot of stylesheets in the head](https://i.ibb.co/bbhgKNX/Screen-Shot-2019-04-03-at-11-12-22-AM.png)

These `style` tags are all absent in the `head` when in `production` mode.

I have narrowed it down to the fact that it seems to be caused by the webpack minification step. If I add

```
optimization: {
  minimize: false
}
```

to my `webpack.config.js`, then the styles are present when in `production` mode.

Here's my `webpack.config.js` without the `optimization` added:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const pathLib = require('path');

const devBuild = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const config = {
  entry: [
    'es5-shim/es5-shim',
    'es5-shim/es5-sham',
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/bundles/analytic',
    './app/bundles/Pulse/startup/registration',
  ],
  output: {
    filename: 'webpack-bundle.js',
    path: pathLib.resolve(__dirname, '../app/assets/webpack'),
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({ NODE_ENV: 'development' }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /travel-info-type.ts/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'TravelInfoType'
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /heatmap-getter.ts/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'HeatmapGetter'
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /data-hub.ts/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'DataHub'
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /exported-functions.js/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'ExportedFunctions'
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /analyticsTracker.ts/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'analyticsTracker'
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /railsAnalytics.js/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'railsAnalytics'
        }]
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve('react'),
        use: {
          loader: 'imports-loader',
          options: {
            shim: 'es5-shim/es5-shim',
            sham: 'es5-shim/es5-sham',
          }
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg|gif|png)$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'url-loader'
        }],
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'ts-loader'.
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },

      // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
      { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" },
      // Extract css files
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [ "style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader" ],
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = config;

if (devBuild) {
  console.log('Webpack dev build for Rails'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
  module.exports.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
} else {
  console.log('Webpack production build for Rails'); // eslint-disable-line no-console
}
```

And here is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "myProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build:test": "webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "build:production": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode=production --config webpack.config.js",
    "build:development": "webpack --mode=development -w --config webpack.config.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "yarn test --watch",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -o ../public/storybook"
  },
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "client/node_modules"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "actioncable": "^5.2.0",
    "color-convert": "^1.9.0",
    "es5-shim": "^4.5.9",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.7",
    "rc-slider": "^8.6.7",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-on-rails": "6.9.3",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^5.11.1",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-select": "^2.3.0",
    "react-table": "^6.0.5",
    "react-toggle-switch": "^2.1.3",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.6.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-batched-actions": "^0.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^3.4.11",
    "@storybook/addons": "^3.4.11",
    "@storybook/react": "^3.4.11",
    "@types/actioncable": "^0.0.2",
    "@types/bugsnag": "^2.5.28",
    "@types/google-maps": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.26.11",
    "@types/highcharts": "^4.2.55",
    "@types/jest": "23.3.10",
    "@types/jquery": "^2.0.45",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.118",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/rc-slider": "^8.6.3",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.1",
    "@types/react-dates": "^16.0.5",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.0.11",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.0.1",
    "@types/react-router": "^4.0.26",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.7",
    "@types/react-select": "^2.0.11",
    "@types/react-tooltip": "^3.3.5",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "babel-cli": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.8.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.9.0",
    "highcharts": "^6.0.3",
    "jest": "23.3.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^10.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.7.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "sinon": "^2.4.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "storybook-addon-jsx": "^5.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.1",
    "ts-jest": "23.10.5",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

And here is the component that is using the `Select` component:

```
import * as React from 'react'

import Select from 'react-select'

import { MultiSelectOption } from '../interfaces/SelectionUI'

class MultipleSelectPicker extends React.PureComponent<MultipleSelectPickerProps> {

  onChange = (allSelected: MultiSelectOption[]) => {
    const {
      onAdd,
      onRemove,
      values,
    } = this.props

    if (values.length < allSelected.length) {
      const addedOption = allSelected.find(selected => !values.includes(selected))

      onAdd(addedOption)
    }
    else if (values.length > allSelected.length) {
      const removedOption = values.find(value => !allSelected.includes(value))

      onRemove(removedOption)
    }
  }

  render() {

    const {
      name,
      values,
      options,
      placeholder,
    } = this.props

    return (
      <Select
        name={name}
        value={values}
        className={`${name} selectpicker`}
        options={options}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        isMulti
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
    )
  }
}

export interface MultipleSelectPickerProps {
  name: string,
  options: MultiSelectOption[],
  values: MultiSelectOption[],
  placeholder?: string,
  onAdd: (addedOption: MultiSelectOption) => void,
  onRemove: (removedOption: MultiSelectOption) => void,
}

export default MultipleSelectPicker
```

Anyone have an idea about why the Webpack 4 minimization would keep the `react-select` Emotion stylesheets from getting injected and how to fix that?

Comment: Could you share the code of a component using react-select?

Comment: @etarhan Yep, I just added that to the question.

Comment: This might be overzealous dead code elimination. I think I'm seeing a similar issue with Webpack 5 and using terser-webpack-plugin. Or it could be CSP...

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. I swapped out the default webpack minimizer for the (UglifyJsPlugin)[https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin] and now everything works as expected.

```
  const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

  optimization: {
    minimizer: [ new UglifyJsPlugin() ],
  }
```